# deploy laravel 5 on debian 7.5, use apache2 to host

Tags: laravel, debian, apache2

I need help on deploy laravel 5 project on debian 7.5,i am not sure where is the problem.
My host configuration like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName stockhit.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/stockhitsite/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/stockhiterror.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/stockhitaccess.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/stockhitsite/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When i access the site by url,  the default laravel welcome page does not show, indeed, it shows the **/public/index.php** file's contents
please help me out, i am trapped here by days，thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is PHP is not enabled on your server. Open Apache config file (usually it's `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`) and uncomment this or similar line:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Comment: thx alex, i think u got the right way, however i cannot find similar lines on debian appache do u know which file it is? debian 7&apache2 dont have httpd.conf file

Comment: Do you have `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`? Is this a shared host, local machine or something else?